# Adding a button in CKEditor for KCFinder

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I have CKEditor running with [KCFinder](http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/) integrated and working, but the application will be used by people with little-to-no computing experience and I would therefore like a button in the CKEditor toolbar which looks like the current Image button but jumps straight to KCFinder.

If you imagine looking at CKEditor, clicking "Image" then "Browser Server", I'd like to basically cut out the middle step of CKeditor's initial popup.

Ideally though, users would still be able to right-click on the image and click "Image Properties" to view CKEditor's popup.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requires a custom plugin and cannot be accomplished as easily as hoped.